# Implement camera lib with Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to understand what structure should have a multiplatform library. Checking on the Internet I've seen a huge number of examples explaining how to make a log or a "hello world" but there's a lack of complex examples, even in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) (important to note that I'm only interested in mobile platform, iOS and Android).

So I want to create an example that simply opens the camera (as a lib, not as a multiplatform app) just to have an idea of how to work with a real feature which, also, is native. Right now I have created a project following the [official example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction), so it has a common module (using expect) and one for Android and one for iOS (using actual), and now these are my doubts:

- I've seen that the iOS module is also in Kotlin, Kotlin/Native as I understand. Should my project have also an wrapper in Swift, or will the library have no Swift code? And if it should, where should it be in the project structure?
- Also in the Android module I've noticed I cannot import the class "Activity" nor the "Intent", which I will need to open the camera, why? is this code restricted to Java without the Android libs? Should it also have a wrapper to Android? If so, how can I configure this wrappers?
- I know I can use the "expect" key when creating classes but, as I understand, the common and the native modules will always be separated classes. I mean, if I create a class in the common module, can I define methods of this class using "expect" and define them later in the native?
- Can my lib have a Manifest?
- Finally, does anyone knows a real example that really explain a more complex situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's go through your questions one-by-one.

1. I would recommend you to have a look at [this](https://github.com/AAkira/mpp-example) example
2. The
       iOS module produces an  Objective-C framework as a result. It can be utilized by the Xcode project the same way as any other framework with non-Kotlin origins.
3. It looks like the unavailability to use
           Android SDK is the result of using `jvm("android")` target instead
           of `android()` one. To use the android target, one has to apply the android Gradle plugin in addition to kotlin-multiplatform one.
4. I
       think you want to do something like that: just ordinary class
       declaration in the `common`  and extension function for it with an
       `expect` modifier. And then actualize it in the platform-specific
       code.
5. I think so.
6. I'd also recommend you to have a look at
       [this](https://github.com/touchlab/DroidconKotlin) and [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinconf-spinner), maybe these examples will be complex enough for you.

Comment: Okey I'll take a look at the examples to see if I can understand better the structure, thanks!